# c programming linked list compiles but segfaults

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

code can be found here https://pastebin.com/DuxzjSsr

i compiled with gcc -g and run in gdb and it says the segfault happens at

```
while(current != NULL){
   current = current->next
}
```

i cant understand why, i copied the code from this link https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists for printing out a linked list etc and the code is pretty much the same as far as i can tell.

Comment: Are you certain that `current->next` is always initialized to either `NULL` or a valid memory address?

Comment: Please do not post code as an external link where it can become inaccessible. Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you never properly initialize `next`. So the value is  to likely be "garbage" data leftover in memory. Here you create a `clist` variable and **only set** the `data` property:

```
  clist mylist;
  mylist.data = "First string";
```

The issue is you don't do `mylist.next = NULL;`, so whatever happened to be at that location is still there, and your code will attempt to assign that value to `current` in your list iteration, `current = current->next`. This may cause a segfault. You are attempting to access memory at an arbitrary location and the result is undefined behavior. As a rule of thumb, always initialize pointers or assign their value to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you initialize the head of the list wrong. Except of the data member, **you should also initialize the next pointer *so it does not point at some garbage value***. When your print function reads that pointer(or any other function) it will crash.

Add this to your main

```cpp
mylist.next = NULL;
```

Also the insertion of your data has the same mistake(line 34-35)

```cpp
current->next = (clist *)malloc(sizeof(clist));
current->next->data = strtoadd;
```

This line will do the trick for data insertion

```cpp
current->next->data->next = NULL;
```